# Meta link on footer

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, per-site-meta, footer

I use Stack Overflow, Super User, [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tour), etc. in the Stack Exchange network. I know that there are multiple `meta` sites like meta.stackoverflow.com, meta.superuser.com, etc.

There are various links in the bottom footer and in that **[meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)** is there. It is linked to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ not only on Stack Overflow, but also on other sites like Super User, Webmasters, etc. I think it will be more useful if that link is dynamic, carrying the corresponding site's meta link - like http://meta.superuser.com/ on superuser.com.

It is a small suggestion from my side to the moderators, to improve our site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The per-site meta is linked at the *top* of the page. The footer is where they promote all the *other* sites in the network. Since this is the global meta, it gets mentioned there too.

Answer (score 3):

The Meta link is there because Meta SO does not only serve as the SO site specific Meta (for now). If you look at the FAQ of Meta SO, you will notice it also serves as a Meta for the SE network as a whole, Stack Overflow Careers and various other topics.

As listed in the FAQ:

> If your question is about:
>
> - Stack Overflow
> - Stack Exchange
> - Stack Overflow Careers
> - Promotions & Advertising
> - Support, feature requests, or bug reports for the core Stack Exchange engine that powers all Stack Exchange websites
>
> … it is welcome here.